# "resources :post, except: :new" makes Rails think the route /posts/new would point to a post ID "new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have the following route:

```
resources :success_criteria, except: :new
```

The following spec fails:

```
describe SuccessCriteriaController do
  describe 'routing' do
    it 'routes to #new' do
      expect(get('/success_criteria/new')).to_not be_routable
    end
  end
end
```

Failure message:

```
Failure/Error: expect(get('/posts/new')).to_not be_routable
expected {:get=>"/posts/new"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show", :id=>"new"}
```

The controller looks like this:

```
class SuccessCriteriaController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

Why does Rails think that `posts/new` would point to a post with the ID `new`? That's not right, is it? Does it maybe have to do with InheritedResources?

Comment: may be you should declare route for single resource?  `resource :success_criteria, except: :new`

Comment: I think you're right to be concerned about InheritedResources. Why is posts/new mapping to a 'show' action? There's an underlying misdirection, it would seem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you don't add a constraint to your `show` route saying that it will only accept digits, everything you put after `posts` are mapped to be an `id` to that route.

That means that if your try to access `posts/something` it would probably throw an `ActiveRecord` error showing that it couldn't find the `Post` with `id=something`.

To add a constraint, add `constraints` like this:

```
resources :success_criteria, except: :new, constraints: { id: /\d+/ }
```