# Understanding constraints in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have been putting tests together to ensure that some CRUD actions are not routable in my application based upon this resource declaration

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :categories
end
```

My Rspec Controller test

```
it 'does not route to #new' do
  expect(get: '/posts/new').to_not be_routable
end
```

When I run this test I get the following output

```
expected {:get=>"/posts/new"} not to be routable, but it routes to {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show", :id=>"new"}
```

So after some research I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809636/resources-post-except-new-makes-rails-think-the-route-posts-new-would-poi) post on SO, having read it an implementing the solution using constraints.

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show], except: :new, constraints: { id: /\d+/ } do
  resources :categories
end
```

Now my tests pass, but I don't understand why and can't leave it without understanding it. So I have two questions

1. Why was the test failing in the beginning?
2. How did adding the constraints argument fix it?

Answer (score 3):

According the the post you linked, and the answer you implemented,

The difference between

```
'/posts/new' # which is the route to the new action of post controller
```

and

```
'/posts/:id' #which is the route to the show action of the same controller
```

is almost nothing, apart from the fact that one is `/new` and the other is `/:id`

Now, this difference is almost nothing, given that having a route like `/posts/:id` means that the only thing really needed here is the `/posts/` part. any other thing in front of this will be seen as an `id` for `/posts/:id`.

To this effect, `/posts/5`, `/posts/10`, `/posts/you`, `/posts/me`, and even `/posts/new` all matches `/posts/:id`. with `:id` equaling => 5, 10, you, me, new respectively.

The above is the reason why your test failed because going to `/posts/new` is routable for the show action, which essentially is `/posts/:id`

On the other hand, when you added the constraint ( id: /\d+/ ), you are telling the route that `id` should be strictly digits. This will prevent any character that is not a digit from being interpreted as an `id`, so, from the example above, ( `/posts/5`, `/posts/10`, `/posts/you`, `/posts/me`, and even `/posts/new` ), only `posts/5` and `/posts/10` will match the show action, while the rest will not.

Hope this is well explanatory ...

Answer (score 1):

1) Your test was failing initially because of the `:show` route for `:posts`. It would look something like this:

```
GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts/#show
```

This will match any `GET` request to /posts/xxxx and will assign whatever you put in the second part of the path (`xxxx` in this case) to the :id element in your `params` hash.

If you inspect the `params[:id]` value in your `show` action after browsing to `/posts/new` you'll see that `params[:id] == 'new'`

**So why did your test fail?**

In your test, you are checking that `/posts/new` doesn't route anywhere. But without any constraints on what is an acceptable value for `:id`, it will route to your show action.

2) The constraint you added specifies that the `:id` parameter must match the regular expression `/\d+/` in order to be accepted. This is one or more digits (0-9).

So, `GET /posts/123` is accepted, but `GET /posts/new` is not. Incidentally, this constraint will prohibit you from using friendly ids to make your URLs nicer. eg `GET /posts/my-new-post-about-something` will not be acceptable due to the constraint specifying that any argument be an integer.

Comment: yes I have just found that Friendly ID has stopped working. Is there a way to get around this or does it not actually matter that the route `posts/new` exists?

Comment: It doesn't really matter that the route `posts/new` exists, providing that you're gracefully handling 404s for your posts, either by redirecting somewhere with a nice message, or by displaying a helpful 404 error page. In this case, you're probably better off just deleting the test rather than adding constraints to your routes.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is what I think happened.

If you put back your original code:

```
resources :posts, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :categories
end
```

and run `rake routes`, you will see that `get posts/new` can be matched in term to one of the `/posts/:id` route with `:id` being matched to the string "new".

Adding the contraint that id must be numeric does not allow for this match to happen anymore.

Note that if you were using mongoid instead of activerecord for instance, your contraint would not work since ids are string.